# Sympy - Comparing expressions

Tags: python, sympy, comparison-operators

Is there a way to check if two expressions are mathematically equal? I expected
`tg(x)cos(x) == sin(x)` to output `True`, but it outputs `False`. Is there a way to make such comparisons with sympy? Another example is 
`(a+b)**2 == a**2 + 2*a*b + b**2` which surprisingly also outputs `False`.

I found some similar questions, but none covered this exact problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From [the SymPy documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/gotchas.html#equals-signs)

> `==` represents exact structural equality testing. “Exact” here means that two expressions will compare equal with == only if they are exactly equal structurally. Here, (x+1)^2 and x^2+2x+1 are not the same symbolically. One is the power of an addition of two terms, and the other is the addition of three terms.
>
> It turns out that when using SymPy as a library, having `==` test for exact symbolic equality is far more useful than having it represent symbolic equality, or having it test for mathematical equality. However, as a new user, you will probably care more about the latter two. We have already seen an alternative to representing equalities symbolically, Eq. To test if two things are equal, it is best to recall the basic fact that if a=b, then a−b=0. Thus, the best way to check if a=b is to take a−b and simplify it, and see if it goes to 0. We will learn later that the function to do this is called [`simplify`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/simplify/simplify.html). This method is not infallible—in fact, it can be theoretically proven that it is impossible to determine if two symbolic expressions are identically equal in general—but for most common expressions, it works quite well.

As a demo for your particular question, we can use the subtraction of equivalent expressions and compare to 0 like so

```
>>> from sympy import simplify
>>> from sympy.abc import x,y
>>> vers1 = (x+y)**2
>>> vers2 = x**2 + 2*x*y + y**2
>>> simplify(vers1-vers2) == 0
True
>>> simplify(vers1+vers2) == 0
False
```

Comment: Note if you have boolean expressions (where your variables `a, b, ... = sympy.symbols('a b ...', boolean=True)` and you use stuff like `sympy.Or`, `sympy.Xor`, etc.) then you can do `isEquivalent = lambda expr1, expr2: sympy.simplify((expr1 & (~expr2)) | ((~expr1) & expr2))==False`

Comment: It works for polynominals and rational functions but not much other ... e.g. `f1 = log(x)+log(y)` and `f2 = log(x*y)` ... `(f1+f2).simplify()` gives `log(x)+log(y) - log(x*y)` not `0`

Comment: Well @Prokop, if you assume `x` and `y` to be positive the expression is actually 0 otherwise you have the case when both `x` and `y` are negative and the identity is correctly not verified.

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively you can use the `.equals` method to compare expressions:

```py
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')

expr1 = tan(x) * cos(x)
expr2 = sin(x)

expr1.equals(expr2)

True
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution with simplify was too slow for me (had to crosscheck multiple variables), so I wrote the following function, which does some simple checkes beforehand, to reduce computational time, to use simplify only in the last step.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

def check_equal(Expr1,Expr2):
    if Expr1==None or Expr2==None:
        return(False)
    if Expr1.free_symbols!=Expr2.free_symbols:
        return(False)
    vars = Expr1.free_symbols
    your_values=np.random.random(len(vars))
    Expr1_num=Expr1
    Expr2_num=Expr2
    for symbol,number in zip(vars, your_values):
        Expr1_num=Expr1_num.subs(symbol, sp.Float(number))
        Expr2_num=Expr2_num.subs(symbol, sp.Float(number))
    Expr1_num=float(Expr1_num)
    Expr2_num=float(Expr2_num)
    if not np.allclose(Expr1_num,Expr2_num):
        return(False)
    if (Expr1.equals(Expr2)):
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False)
```

Comment: Great solution. The for loop can be simplified to just    `Expr1_num=Expr1_num.subs(zip(vars, your_values))`
`Expr2_num=Expr2_num.subs(zip(vars, your_values))`. Sympy can substitute multiple tuples at once.

Comment: There is a typo, `Expr1_num=float(Expr2_num)` should be `Expr1_num=float(Expr1_num)`, otherwise this always returns true.

Comment: Edited code to correct the typo

Answer (score 1):

As previously stated, `(expr1 - expr2).simplify()` or `expr1.equals(expr2)` will sometimes fail to recognize equality for expressions that are complex to simplify. To deal with this, a numerical evaluation of the expressions with random numbers may constitute a relatively safe "brute force" test. I've adapted the excellent solution by @Okapi575 to:

1. Test the numerical equality N-times with different random numbers each time for a more confident diagnostic
2. Warn the user when a pair of expressions only passes the numeric test but not the symbolic equality test.

For example:

[image: Example of test for equality]

Hope it can prove useful:

```py
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

def check_equal(Expr1, Expr2, n=10, positive=False, strictly_positive=False):
    
    # Determine over what range to generate random numbers
    sample_min = -1
    sample_max = 1
    if positive:
        sample_min = 0
        sample_max = 1
    if strictly_positive:
        sample_min = 1
        sample_max = 2
    
    # Regroup all free symbols from both expressions
    free_symbols = set(Expr1.free_symbols) | set(Expr2.free_symbols)
    
    # Numeric (brute force) equality testing n-times
    for i in range(n):
        your_values=np.random.uniform(sample_min, sample_max, len(free_symbols))
        Expr1_num=Expr1
        Expr2_num=Expr2
        for symbol,number in zip(free_symbols, your_values):
            Expr1_num=Expr1_num.subs(symbol, sp.Float(number))
            Expr2_num=Expr2_num.subs(symbol, sp.Float(number))
        Expr1_num=float(Expr2_num)
        Expr2_num=float(Expr2_num)
        if not np.allclose(Expr1_num, Expr2_num):
            print("Fails numerical test")
            return(False)
        
    # If all goes well so far, check symbolic equality
    if (Expr1.equals(Expr2)):
        return(True)

    else:
        print("Passes the numerical test but not the symbolic test")
        # Still returns true though
        return(True)
```

**EDIT**: code updated (1) to compare expressions with differing numbers of free symbols (for example, after symbols got cancelled out during a simplification), and (2) to allow for the specification of a positive or strictly positive random number range.

Comment: doesn't work on my test with two expressions that are not the same, it returns numerically identical which is false: exp1=0.5*x**4 - 1.0*x**3 + 2.5*x**2 - 2.0*x + 1.0, exp2=1.5*x**4 - 3.0*x**3 + 3.5*x**2 - 2.0*x + 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Check this out from the original sympy themselves.
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Faq
[image]

Example of it working for me
[image]