# Why doesn't SymPy understand log product

Tags: python, sympy

Why does the following return `False`?

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol('x')
y = sp.Symbol('y')

sp.log(x*y) == sp.log(x) + sp.log(y)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an underlying assumption for this rule that your variables are positive. SymPy won't perform this simplification (correctly) if this is not indicated.

To make this assumption clear to SymPy,

```
x = sp.Symbol('x', positive=True)
y = sp.Symbol('y', positive=True)
```

Now [read this Q/A on equality in SymPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112738/sympy-comparing-expressions) to see that you ought to be `simplify`ing in your comparison.

```
>>> sp.simplify(sp.log(x*y) - (sp.log(x) + sp.log(y))) == 0
True
```