# In the Sympy library of Python, why does "apart(f) == f" return False if they are actually different version of the same expressions?

Tags: python, sympy

I am learning Sympy and found it strange that a manipulation of a function yielding the same function but simplified would be considered different than the original function, even though they are mathematically equal.

[what I mean in a Jupiter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgybW.png)

Comment: I think you can find the reason here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37115190/11004559

Comment: Yes! That is perfect, thank you!