# Unexpected result in Trace function sympy: Trace(A*B) not equal to Trace(B*A)

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am puzzled about why the following code produces False in sympy, Python

```
import sympy
from sympy import MatrixSymbol, Trace

A = MatrixSymbol('A', 3, 3)
B = MatrixSymbol('B', 3, 3)

Trace(A*B)==Trace(B*A)
```

while it is well-known that Tr(A*B)=Tr(B*A) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Trace_of_a_product

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That's because `==` checks for exact structural equality not equality in the mathematical sense. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112738/sympy-comparing-expressions

Comment: @user2640045 Thanks, that actually solves it

Comment: @user2640045 I just tried `simplify(Trace(B*A)-Trace(A*B))==0` and it still gives me `False`. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Have you looked at the result of `simplify(Trace(B*A)-Trace(A*B))`? I would guess that sympy failed to simplify that.

Comment: Yeah, `simplify(Trace(B*A)-Trace(A*B))` gave me `Trace(B*A)-Trace(A*B)`. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I see you're not happy with letting it go. Here is how you actually get sympy to calculate that for you

```
from sympy import shape, Matrix, symbols, trace
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

A = Matrix(np.array(symbols([f"a_{i}{j}" for i,j in product(range(1,4),range(1,4))])).reshape(3,3))
B = Matrix(np.array(symbols([f"b_{i}{j}" for i,j in product(range(1,4),range(1,4))])).reshape(3,3))
trace(A*B)-trace(B*A) == 0
```

Which finally gives you `True`.